# Configuring HCatalog, WebHCat with Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hcatalog

I'm installing **Hadoop**, **Hive** to be integrated with **WebHCat** which will be used to run hive queries through it using Map-Reduce jobs of Hadoop.

I installed **Hadoop 2.4.1** and **Hive 0.13.0** (latest stable versions).

The request I'm sending using the web interface is:

```
POST: http://localhost:50111/templeton/v1/hive?user.name='hadoop'&statusdir='out'&execute='show tables'
```

And I got response as the following:

```
{
    "id": "job_local229830426_0001"
}
```

But in the logs **webhcat-console-error.log** I find that exit value of this job is 1, which means some error occurred. Tracking this error I found it **Missing argument for option: hiveconf**

This is the **webhcat-site.xml** which contains the configurations of webhcat (known previously as templeton):

```
<configuration>
  <property>
      <name>templeton.port</name>
      <value>50111</value>
      <description>The HTTP port for the main server.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>templeton.hive.path</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hive/bin/hive</value>
    <description>The path to the Hive executable.</description>
 </property>
  <property>
    <name>templeton.hive.properties</name>
    <value>hive.metastore.local=false,hive.metastore.uris=thrift://localhost:9933,hive.metastore.sasl.enabled=false</value>
    <description>Properties to set when running hive.</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

But the cmd query executed is weird as it have some additional hiveconf parameters with no values:

```
tool.TrivialExecService: Starting cmd: [/usr/local/hive/bin/hive, --service, cli, --hiveconf, --hiveconf, --hiveconf, hive.metastore.local=false, --hiveconf, hive.metastore.uris=thrift://localhost:9933, --hiveconf, hive.metastore.sasl.enabled=false, -e, show tables]
```

Any Idea?

Comment: This is happening since its picking up the default values of metastore URIS and other ones. If you want to change it you will have to explicitly specify them in templeton.hive.properties